# Solve first order ordinary differential equation (ODE).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

I have a parametrized curve 
$$f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$$ such that $f(t)=x(t)+y(t)$
and the  tangent vector $X(f(t))=(-p(t),q(t))$

then ,the curve satisfy the first ordinary differential equation
is get by equation  such that

$$\langle \dot{f}(t),X(f(t))\rangle=-\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial x(t)}p(t)+\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial y(t)}q(t)=0$$

I need to solve this equations and plot it(Or only plot it as a special case for geometric properties

Can they be considered as an first order ordinary differential equation (ODE).

Is there a solution? Is it possible to use a software program for solving and drawing

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the meaning of those letters, which functions are given, what are the unknowns? The only explicitely given entity is $0$, and you won't get much of a drawing out of that, I'm afraid. So I think your statement of the problem is somewhat incomplete.

Comment: Equation $(1)$ actually follows from equation $(2)$.

Comment: @John Wayland Bales How exactly would if follow? I'm especially interested in the magical appearance and meaning of $g$.

Comment: It's too long for a comment, I'm working on it and will submit it as a partial answer.

Comment: @ProfessorVector If the hypothesis is that p(t) and q(t) are constants,You could solve using mathematica as `pde = c_1D[f[x, y], y] + c_2 D[f[x, y], x] == 0` `soln = DSolve[pde, f[x, y], {x, y}]`

Comment: It would be advisable to write every bit of information, assumptions, definitions,... in your question. I'm pretty sure you can't write DSolve[pde, f[x, y], {x, y}] in Mathematica without definining f, first. And there's a "pde" in that line, and "ODE" in the title. So what is your question?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I hope you can solve it. thanks for the help

Comment: @ProfessorVector  No, I made an error. I retract my claim that $(1)$ follows from $(2)$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I will update the question

Comment: Well, I can get the following but do not know where to go with it. $p(t)\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dt}+q(t)\left(\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)\cdot\dfrac{dx}{dt}=0$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales see new update

Comment: @ProfessorVector  see new update

Comment: is this an ODE? looks like PDE to me

Comment: @Math_QED I am a beginner in this specialty, but I see it as  linear homogeneous equation.  Can you help me to get the best idea